# How can I visualise categorical feature vs date column

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

In my dataset I have a categorical column named 'Type'contain(eg.,INVOICE,IPC,IP) and 'Date' column contain dates(eg,2014-02-01).
how can I plot these two.
On x axis I want date
On y axis a line for (eg.INVOCE) showing its trend

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/la0rc.jpg)

Comment: what is the value on the `y` axis? The count for each type of document?

Comment: X axis contain dates and y axis have ['GR' 'INQUIRY' 'INVOICE' 'IP' 'IPC' 'PRE_APPROVAL'] you can find the data frame above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not very sure what you mean by plot and show trend, one ways is to count like @QuangHoang suggested, and plot with a heatmap, something like below. If it is something different, please expand on your question.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

dates = pd.date_range(start='1/1/2018', periods=5, freq='3M')[np.random.randint(0,5,20)]
type = np.random.choice(['INVOICE','IPC','IP'],20)
df = pd.DataFrame({'dates':dates ,'type':type})
tab = pd.crosstab(df['type'],df['dates'].dt.strftime('%d-%m-%Y'))
n = np.unique(tab.values)
cmap = sns.color_palette("BuGn_r",len(n))
sns.heatmap(tab,cmap=cmap)
```

[image]

Comment: i have added the dataframe

Comment: Ok please don't paste images. You can use the code above. just apply the variable names correctly

Comment: but what is tab.values.

Comment: sorry it's ok now. for ```tab = pd.crosstab(df['type'],df['dates'].dt.strftime('%d-%m-%Y'))```, you might not need the .dt. part. try pd.crosstab(df['Type'],df['Date']) in your data frame.. next time provide the data.frame